# How to open second link in the same iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have this code:

```
<script>
function releu1On() {
 var url = 'http://10.10.5.155/30000/01';
 var elem = document.createElement('a');
 setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="http://10.10.5.155/30000/00"} , 1000);
 elem.href = url;
 elem.target = 'hiddenIframe';
 elem.click();
}
</script>

<iframe style="display:none;" name="hiddenIframe" id="hiddenIframe"></iframe>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="releu1On()"/>1. On</button>
```

I want the second link, from `setTimeout` condition to open in the same iframe after a certain number seconds, without following/loading in page. I want it to be hidden.

Comment: var $ip = $('a').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'yourid',
    name: 'yourname',
    href: url 
})
$(hiddenIframe).appendTo('body');

Comment: I am sorry but i don't know where to insert that code :)

Comment: do you want to create both link after certain time or one on load and second after some time ?

Comment: I want when i click a button to load first link and after some seconds to load the next link but in the same hiddden iframe.

Comment: See the code below I have modified your method

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your method see below:

```
   function releu1On() {

    var firstLink = document.createElement("a");

    firstLink.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

    firstLink.setAttribute("name", "name_you_want");

    firstLink.setAttribute("href", "http://10.10.5.155/30000/01");

      $('#hiddenIframe').contents().find('body').append(firstLink);

    setTimeout(function(){    

        var secondLink = document.createElement("a");

          secondLink.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

          secondLink.setAttribute("name", "name_you_want");

          secondLink.setAttribute("href", "http://10.10.5.155/30000/00");

          $('#hiddenIframe').contents().find('body').append(secondLink);

  } , 1000);

}
```

Comment: <script>
function releu1On() {
 var url = 'https://www.emag.ro';
 var elem = document.createElement('a');
 setTimeout(function(){

    var $ip = $('a').attr({ type: 'hidden', id: 'yourid', name: 'yourname', href: "https://www.bilzone.ro" }) ;
    $($ip).appendTo('hiddenIframe');

  } ,2000);
 elem.href = url;
 elem.target = 'hiddenIframe';
 elem.click();
}
 </script>

Comment: I tested using that code but seems to not work or i missing something.

Comment: Yes there is a mistake in your given code see my code again, I have updated it

Comment: the same as last time

Comment: You should specify that you're using `jQuery` and not plain JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, my mistake

Comment: To explain what im trying to do:
- first link activate a relay and second link disable that relay and I want to do this automatically without second click on that button.

Comment: And all of these actions to be invisible, loading in that iframe that is hidden, whitout following that link to be visible in the page.

Comment: @RobertMihaiMancas I have updated my code and convert my code to JavaScript and its woring for me

Comment: The code posted by me it working but when arrive to the second link he loading on the page not in the hidden iframe. I hope I explained it well. Sorry for my english.

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER I don't know why but for me is not working. I don't know where i'm wrong

This is my code: https://pastebin.com/8YrBNdbT

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER - any other help. I've been tested all the variants but same result.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded with the following code:

```
function releu1On() {
 var url = 'http://10.10.5.155/30000/01';
 var elem = document.createElement('a');
 setTimeout("document.getElementById('hiddenIframe').src = 'http://10.10.5.155/30000/00';",2000);
 elem.href = url;
 elem.target = 'hiddenIframe';
 elem.click();
}
```